# Get array slices in length order

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following code to get a list of all possible slice start/end indexes, in order of descending slice length. I then iterate over the list and use it to slice up an array, breaking when I get a slice that I am looking for. I do this because I am looking for the largest slice that matches other parameters and I am looking to short cut past the other possible slices once I've found one.

I would prefer a couple of nested for loops to check the slice and move on, instead of having to get every possible range and sort them first, since the array can be up to a billion or so items large. I can't for the life of me figure out how to do it, or even how to phrase the question to search for it. Any help is appreciated.

```
byte[] data1 = { 54, 87, 23, 87, 45, 67, 7, 85, 65, 65, 3, 4, 55, 76, 65, 64, 5, 6, 4, 54, 45, 6, 4 };

List<Tuple<int, int>> ranges = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
for (int i1 = 0; i1 < data1.Count(); i1++)
{
    for (int i2 = i1 + 1; i2 < data1.Count(); i2++)
    {
        ranges.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(i1, i2));
    }
}


ranges = ranges.OrderByDescending(x => x.Item2 - x.Item1).ToList();
```

Comment: `ranges` is not thread safe, you can't call `ranges.Add` inside parallel code without locking. Also, there is 0 reason for this code to be parallel, you get no advantage from it, you are not doing any kind of CPU intensive processing, you are just adding a ton of items to a list. Make the code work without using threading first, then if it is too slow, try adding threading later.

Comment: I figured that since this grows exponentially with array size, I would go ahead and speed up what I could. It compiles and runs as expected. Would I see locking every run, or is it just a possible run time error.

Comment: I am very shocked it runs as expected, you should have had lost or duplicate entries in `ranges`, possibly even run time exceptions. You would not "see locking" you need to "do locking" but your code isn't, and sence you are not doing anything except calling `add` the locking will make the code not parallel, so there is no reason to use the `Parallel.For` and just use two normal `for`.

Comment: Ok, I got rid of threading. Do you have any insights on my original question?

Comment: If you have a byte array that big, you already have a problem, before iterating it. You should be streaming the data in from a file/socket etc. What kind of other parameters are you matching against?

Comment: I'm unclear on your goal, but the number of ranges that are produced can be calculated by the formula:  `(L - 1) * L / 2` where: L = data1.Length.  Use that value as the argument in the `List` constructor.  Doing so will eliminate the need for the List to dynamically reallocate as you add values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you are looking for the largest subarray of an array (which you are calling a "slice"…maybe a term from some other programming language?) that meets some specific conditions. In your question, you are unspecific about the conditions themselves, so I assume that part is not important.

It seems what you are having difficulty with is arranging your code so that you necessarily inspect the longest subarrays first.

If all of that is correct, then you just need to arrange your loops differently. Currently, you are picking a starting index and then finding all subarrays that start at that index. Instead, since you want the longest subarrays to be inspect first, you should pick the *length* of the subarray, starting with the longest possible length, and select all subarrays that can be that long.

For example:

```
for (int i = data1.Length; i > 0; i--)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < data1.Length - i + 1; j++)
    {
        // inspect subarray starting at index j, having length i
    }
}
```

Comment: This came very close to what I needed. I had to modify it a bit, but this definitely put my on the right path. Thanks.

Comment: Also, yeah slice originally came from my PERL days, and then I saw it again in some JS scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You may enumerate the slices directly by a couple of nested loops:

```
bool found = false;
for (int sliceLen = data1.Length; !found && sliceLen > 0; sliceLen--)
    for (int sliceStart = 0; !found && sliceStart + sliceLen <= data1.Length; sliceStart++)
        if (found = (
            data1[sliceStart] == data1[sliceStart + sliceLen - 1]   // check your condition here
        ))
            Console.WriteLine($"Found: {sliceStart}:{sliceLen}");
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/lZRNJm

Comment: This didn't get what I was looking for, but I'm giving you an upvote for the !found. I'm going to replace a bunch of "if (found) {break;}" lines at the ends of loops with that pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Here's what I needed, to iterate over each array slice in reverse length order.

```
byte[] data1 = { 54, 87, 23, 87, 45, 67, 7, 85, 65, 65, 3, 4, 55, 76, 65, 64, 5, 6, 4, 54, 45, 6, 4 };


for (int length = data1.Count() - 1; length > 0; length--)
{
    int numberOfSlicesForLength = data1.Count() - length;

    for (int start = 0; start < numberOfSlicesForLength; start++)
    {
        byte[] sliceValues = data1.Skip(start).Take(length);
    }
}
```